# getting distance between multiple waypoints using php

Tags: php, google-maps

I am using google api to get the distances between multiple waypoints in jquery and javascript. I am able to get the distances between two points using a php script. I am looking for a way to do the same with multiple waypoints using a php script.

Ok I managed to do the following to get the result I wanted

$this-url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?waypoints=wp1lat,wp1lon|wp2lat,wp2lon|wp3lat,wp3lon"

with a call via
        $data = @file_get_contents($this_url);

```
    $result = json_decode($data, true);
```

this returns a json object which can then be parsed with all the relevant info needed.

*NB PLEASE NOTE THAT I AM EXTRACTING THE INFO BUT AM USING IT ON A SCREEN MAP LAYOUT AS PER GOOGLES TERMS. ANY CALL OF THIS TYPE TO GOOGLE MUST HAVE A MAP COMPONENT AS PER THEIR TERMS AND CONDITIONS ;)

Answer (score -3):

Are you looking for a way in js or php?!
In JS you can use gmap APIs:

```
    var meters = parseFloat(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength
 (latlngcollectionArray);
```

PS: remember to include library

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&
libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Comment: I am unfortunately looking for a solution using PHP. I am comfortable with the jquery version. Just need to do it with php